# Matlab - make scanf detect string in single quotes OR a normal string

Tags: matlab

I'm reading a text file using fscanf. Every row starts with 3 floats and ends with either 'aaa bb ccccc' or abc. For example:

```
1.3 1.4 3.5 hello
4.5 66 4.3 'hi there k'
1.3 1.4 3.7 something
```

I'd like to extract only these numbers using fscanf. The single quotes cause a lot of problems, %s doesn't detect the string properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the numbers you can use

```
A = textscan(fid, '%f%f%f%s', 'CommentStyle', {'''' ''''} )
```

...where fid is the file id from `fopen`. This hack works by making the `textscan` command treat the single `'` marks as comments. The syntax looks funky because to define a single quote in a Matlab string, you need to put 4 together `''''`. There are 2 of these in a cell array so that `CommentStyle` treats anything between these chars as a block comment.

Comment: Have you tested that? It doesn't work for me - all I get is the first line.

Comment: Yep. Tested. A is a 1x4 cell array with the vals from each column in each element. The comments between the `'` are ignored, but all the numerical values are in the right position. Copy paste the line above to check you haven't made a typo.

Comment: Why does it return a cell array instead of a usual matrix? What's the point of cell array here...

Comment: `textscan` just gives a bit more control than `fscanf`. It outputs cells. It is ugly, but at least it extracts the data and it is easy enough to combine it however you like.